# Always overwrite write-protected files

Tags: sublimetext3

Sometimes when saving files on shared network folders, Sublime asks me to **Overwrite write-protected file ~/Development/project/style.less?**

Can I make this default somehow, so I don't have to click **Yes** all the time?

Comment: You might be better served by figuring out why the file is write protected. There's probably something going on that you want to fix.

Comment: I added topic on sublime forum: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/add-ability-to-overwrite-all-write-protected-files/26936